# Date picker with custom start date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I am working on a form, for a web application. I have been researching on customizing a date picker plugin. I want to use a  JavaScript/php date picker. But the issue is that the user can only choose date from a particular number. For instance: Today is 02/08/2016, the user can only be allowed to choose a date from 10/08/2016. Any date before the 10/08/2016 cannot be selected. How can i use php to control such functionality? Or is there any better way i can achieve this?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: You can't use PHP for this.  But there are a gazillion javascript date pickers.

Comment: PHP can be used to set the from date like dateFrom: '<?php echo todays date + 2 days; ?>'

Comment: today is 8th-Feb and user can not select date before 8th-Oct?

Comment: @Plum, Thats what am looking for... But the idea is to be on the date picker. In such a way that other Other dates before will not be active or available for selection.

Comment: @AtifTariq, Yes, something like that.

Comment: @PolarB. See my answer. Its also there in Github. Go through the documents properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are looking for this but it is a very simple to use.

**HMTL**

```
<!-- Enter a date after 2016-10-08 (you can make this variable with some php code): -->

<input type="date" name="bday" min="2016-10-08">
```

**With PHP eg.**

```
<input type="date" name="bday" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', (time() + 86400)); ?>">
```

86400 is one day in seconds.

---

See also [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp).

Comment: Thank you for the response, This method will only set a defined date for the user. But i want the user to be able to select any date of choice starting from a particular day.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out this link for bootstrap calendar:- http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/.
 You will all the necessary methods to populate dates in your calendar.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
    $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        startDate: "-1d",
        endDate: "+5d",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: new Date()
});
```